# Improper input: N=3 must not exceed M=1 (error trying to fit a gaussian function)

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I'm pretty new to python and curve fitting and currently I'm trying to fit the graph below with a Gaussian

[image]

I'm following [this tutorial](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html) and my code looks like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import genfromtxt
from matplotlib import pyplot
from numpy import sqrt, pi, exp, linspace,loadtxt
from lmfit import Model

def gaussian(x,amp,cen,wid):
    "1-d gaussian: gaussian(x,amp,cen,wid)"
    return (amp/(sqrt(2*pi)*wid))*exp(-(x-cen)**2/(2*wid**2))


filelist=[]
time=[0.00,-1.33,-2.67,-4.00,-5.33,-6.67,1.13,2.67,4.00,5.33,6.67]
index=0
offset=0

filelist.append('0.asc')

for i in range(1,6):
    filelist.append("-%s00.asc" %(i))

for i in range(1,6):
    filelist.append("+%s00.asc" %(i))

sfgpeaks=[]


for fname in filelist:
    data=np.genfromtxt(fname,delimiter=',',unpack=True,skip_footer=20)
    SFGX=data[0,500:530]
    SFGY=data[1,500:530]
    SFGpeakY=np.max(SFGY)
    sfgpeaks.append(SFGpeakY)

    gmodel = Model(gaussian)
    result = gmodel.fit(SFGpeakY, x=time[index], amp=5,cen=5,wid=3)

    plt.plot(time[index],sfgpeaks[index],'ro')
    plt.plot(time[index],result.init_fit, 'k--',label="Gaussian Fit")

    plt.xticks(time)
    index=index+1

print(pump2SHGX)
pyplot.title("Time Delay-SFG peak")
plt.xlabel("Timedelay[ps]")
plt.ylabel("Counts[arb.unit]")
plt.savefig("796and804nmtimesfg")
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.0,0.5))
plt.show()
```

However, I'm getting an error when I try to add the data that I have(time delay and the Y value of the graph above) into the gaussian parameters.
The error I'm getting is this

> TypeError: Improper input: N=3 must not exceed M=1

Does this error because I'm trying to insert a value from an array into the parameter??

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please add the traceback - where is the error raised?

Comment: Sorry, but this is one of the "read the error message" questions. You want to fit three parameters to a singe point. Note `SFGpeakY=np.max(SFGY)` is one value only, hence `M=1`

Comment: I have the impression that the data you want to fit is made from all files, so you need to make this data set first and the fit must not be inside that loop.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! When I did the fitting outside the loop,it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
 result = gmodel.fit(SFGpeakY, x=time[index], amp=5,cen=5,wid=3)
```

which is passing 1 value as `x` and 1 value as the data. The model is then evaluated at that 1 point.  The error message is the fit is complaining that you have 3 variables and 1 value.

You probably want to fit the data array `SFGY` with `x` set to `SFGX`,

```
 result = gmodel.fit(SFGY, x=SFGX, amp=5,cen=5,wid=3)
```

though it wasn't clear to me what data is used in the plot you attached.

Also: you probably want to give initial values for `amp`, `cen`, and `wid` based on the data.  Your `SFGpeakY` is probably a decent guess for `amp`, and `SFGX.mean()` and `SFGX.std()` are probably decent guesses or `cen` and `wid`.

Also: you plot `result.init_fit` labeled as "Gaussian Fit".   `result.init_fit` will be the model evaluated with the initial values for the parameters.  The best fit with the refined parameters will be in `result.best_fit`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did the fitting outside the loop and the error disappeared. I set Y to the array sfgpeaks and the x to the array time. However, the chi-square value was way too big which meant the data did not even fit the model.. probably have to rethink my data inputs..

Comment: It's hard to know what you did unless you post the code you actually ran. Your original code had lots of extra not-quite-on-message stuff in it. Breaking it down to a minimal example (that will help you too).  Also, you should look at and include the fit report (`print(result.fit_report())`) which will show fit statistics and refined parameter values and uncertainties.